How to loop over Spark Row data?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html
I'm trying to iterate over a row's data items. According to this key in row will search through row keys.
However I don't see this behavior.  Am I missing something???
    data = [{"ID": '  ', "PostCode": ' A ', "Value": 121.44, "Truth": True},
            {"ID": None, "PostCode": '',  "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False},
            {"ID": None, "PostCode": ' C', "Value": 10.99, "Truth": None},
            {"ID": '',   "PostCode": 'E ', "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True}
            ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    df.show()
    cols = [f"any({col} is not null AND trim({col}) != '') as {col}_any_isnot_null_or_empty" for col in df.columns]
    rows = df.selectExpr(cols)
    rows.show()

    row = rows.collect()[0]
    print(type(row))
    asdict = row.asDict()
    for key, val in asdict.items():
        print(key, val)
    print()
    print()
    for thing in row:
        print(thing, row[thing])

I get results
<class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
ID_any_isnot_null_or_empty False
PostCode_any_isnot_null_or_empty True
Truth_any_isnot_null_or_empty True
Value_any_isnot_null_or_empty True


False False
True True
True True
True True

The first set of results is from asDict, which is as expected; you get <colname> True/False, the second set of prints are from for thing in row, which I would have expected to have the same format, but it iterates over the values instead apparently based on the output

What's the expected output?

edited for expected output.
